# Android Safe Args Navigation JetPack OnBackPress in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack

I chose the Safe Args method for passing data between fragments because of type-safty.

Sender fragment

```
        btnNextPage.setOnClickListener{
        val amountTv: EditText = 
view!!.findViewById(R.id.edt_my_argument_view)
        val amount = amountTv.text.toString()
        val action = 
NavFragment01Directions.actionNavFragment01ToNavFragment02(amount)
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action)
    }
```

Receiver fragment

```
private val args: NavFragment02Args by navArgs()
.
.
.
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: 
Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val txtWhole: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_whole_02)
    val receivedTxt = args.myArg
    txtWhole.text = receivedTxt.toString()
}
```

My_nav

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <navigation 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/my_nav"
app:startDestination="@id/navFragment01">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navFragment02"
    android:name="alidoran.android.navigation_safe_args.NavFragment02"
    android:label="fragment_nav02"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_nav02" >
    <argument
        android:name="my_arg"
        android:defaultValue="Ali"
        app:nullable="true" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navFragment01"
    android:name="alidoran.android.navigation_safe_args.NavFragment01"
    android:label="fragment_nav01"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_nav01" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_navFragment01_to_navFragment02"
        app:destination="@id/navFragment02" >
        <argument
            android:name="my_arg"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="@null"
            app:nullable="true" />
    </action>

  </fragment>
</navigation>
```

This is working perfectly.

Now I want to pass a value from the receiver fragment to the sender fragment after pressing the back button.
I know how to do it with Bundle but I want to do it by Safe Args.
Also, I know it is possible to create an action for it but I want to handle it in the back press corresponding to the below map.
[image: Nav route]
As you see we need an action for attaching value(s) but I don't want to create an action from the second one to the first one. I know how to handle it in the back press but I want Safe Args way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using navigation component the best way is by savedStateHandle:

```
findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("key", result)
```

And observe the response with:

```
findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<Type>("key")?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {result ->
    // the result.
}
```

As define in the doc:

> To pass data back to Destination A from Destination B, first set up Destination A to listen for a result on its SavedStateHandle. To do so, retrieve the NavBackStackEntry by using the getCurrentBackStackEntry() API and then observe the LiveData provided by SavedStateHandle.

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result

Comment: This is not the best way, despite it kind of works. Else the documentation wouldn't tell otherwise. One could argue, but `FragmentResultListener` indeed does what it says.

Comment: @MartinZeitler check the documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result

Comment: I know this is technically correct, but manipulating the back-stack still isn't too convincing. Before there was a `FragmentResultListener`, this may have been the only option. And it's probably a matter how much one has to return, while the code stays manageable (the main argument for preferring a listener). When there is a default callback which does the job, I'd suggest to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way is to implement [`FragmentResultListener`](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#pass-between-fragments).
The documentation explain this well, possibly better than I could.

Comment: As I said, I know about the bundle way. I want to implement it with Safe Args way because of type-safety.  
Your suggested way is a bundle method.

Comment: You may have a misconception there, the arguments only apply for the calling direction (it's code generated from XML); the result delivered to the `FragmentResultListener` may contain various types (and there's no XML it could generate code from). It's not alike entering the fragment through forwards navigation. And this is any time better than manipulating the backstack.

Comment: Forward navigation always has 1 origin ...while backwards navigation can have N origins (that's the reason why there is a request key). And if you require type-safety, in Kotlin keyword `is` is the same as in Java `instanceof`.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your explanation. I assumed there is a way that is able to create a type back in XML as the Forward navigation. But, as you said there isn't any way and I should implement it like before

Answer (score 0):

I implemented both methods. I had seen the @davidte suggested method on the internet, but my mistake was I had assumed that the result was back to the first Fragment immediately, so I had not tested it.
surprisingly, After implementation, it worked very well. The result is backed to the first method after backing to the first fragment.
The @Martin-Zeitler suggested method, disadvantages are

1. I didn't have type-safety
2. I have two key values in both fragments.
   eventually, I have chosen @davidte method.

Comment: What you even need type safety for, when it's already known what the types will be? Test this in a `FragmentScenario` and try to get arguments there. With neither approach you get to run the generated type-safety code, which only checks the arguments on forward navigation.